# Походження слова "сусло"

Tags: етимологія

Із [статті](http://1001watch.com.ua/news/7140/) приготування домашнього вина: *Що таке виноградне **сусло** і які маніпуляції потрібно з ним проводити для отримання кінцевого результату?
Виноградне сусло - це заготовка для вина, яка виходить шляхом пресування свіжого винограду.*

З СУМ-11

> ***[СУСЛО](http://sum.in.ua/s/suslo)*** 1. Водний розчин рослинної сировини або солоду, признач. для зброджування при виробництві пива, квасу. *Почалось
>   будівництво цеху по виробництву екстракту сусла, з якого готують
>   хлібний квас* (Вечірній Київ, 5.II 1975, 2).
>
> 2. Відпресований сік винограду. *Сухі вина одержують внаслідок повного зброджування свіжого виноградного сусла з м'язгою або без неї*
>      (Українські страви, 1957, 380).

Цікавить яке походження має слово ***"сусло"***?

Comment: Все-таки хочу сказати, що відповідь шукається в етимолоґічному словнику напряму, тому це питання не зовсім відповідає якості, що ми тут її вимагаємо. Ці питання хай вже будуть, але в майбутньому, будь ласка, користуйтесь таки етимолоґічним словником, бо ви ж бачите, що відповідь - просто стаття з того словника.

Comment: @P.Vovk Все зрозуміла, надалі користуватимусь етимолоґічним словником.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаходимо в [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm):
[image]